# Multiple of $n$ and the sum of its digits is $k\geq n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that for every positive integers $k\geq n$, with $n$ not divisible by $3$, there is a positive integer divisible by $n$ and such that the sum of his digits is $k$.

Comment: Do you have to find one pair of $n,k$ as in the title, or you have to prove "there exists ..." for all pairs of such $n, k$?

Comment: For a fixed n and every k there exists a positive integer

Comment: I asked this a couple of years agosto, ley me ser if O can find It.

Answer (score 0):

IMO ShortList 1999, number theory problem 5
http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h19765p131819